# Logarithm rules in $8^{\log_2 n} = n^{\log_2 8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

what are the log rules in play in this equation:

$$    8^{\log_2 n} = n^{\log_2 8}$$

I can't determine it myself with only the basic log rules.

Comment: Notice $2^3=8$.

Comment: @kingW3 Sorry but this seems off-topic since, for every positive $a$, $b$, $c$, $$a^{\log_bc}=c^{\log_ba}.$$

Comment: Yeah that method seems easier and works for general case,though this method is also correct.
$$8^{\log_2 n}=2^{3\log_2 n}=2^{\log_2 n^3}=n^3$$ and $$n^{\log_2 8}=n^{\log_2 2^3}=n^3$$,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
8^{\log_2 n} = e^{\log_2 n \ln 8} = e^{\ln n \ln 8 / \ln 2}
=e^{\ln n \log_2 8}=n^{\log_2 8}
$$

We don't need to know $2^3 = 8$.  Other numbers would work just as well:
$$
a^{\log_b n} = n^{\log_b a}
$$

Answer (score 1):

taking the logarithm of both sides we get $$\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}\ln(8)=\frac{\ln(8)}{\ln(2)}\ln(n)$$
after simplifying we obtain
$3\ln(n)=3\ln(n)$ which is equivalent to $$n^3=n^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $2^{\log_2 x} = x$, we have $$8^{\log_2 n} = (2^{\log_2 8})^{\log_2 n} = 2^{(\log_2 8)(\log_2 n)}$$ and $$n^{\log_2 8} = (2^{\log_2 n})^{\log_2 8} = 2^{(\log_2 n)(\log_2 8)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the logarithm in base $2$ of both sides;

- left hand side: $\log_2(8^{\log_2n})=\log_2n\log_28$
- right hand side: $\log_2(n^{\log_28})=\log_28\log_2n$

Two numbers having the same logarithm are equal.

Answer (score 0):

$$8^{\log_2 n}=(2^3)^{\log_2 n}=2^{3\cdot (\log_2 n)}=2^{(\log_2 n)\cdot 3}=(2^{\log_2n})^3=n^3=n^{\log_28}$$